# ObservableObject or INotifyPropertyChanged on ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I was curious what was the best thing to do with `ViewModels`. Is it better to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` or to derive from `ObservableObject`.

`ObservableObject` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and do some of the boring code like `RaisePropertyChanged`.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` require to implement `PropertyChanged` event.

From my point of view it seems more logical to use `ObservableObject`, but in most of the tutorial they implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on their `ViewModel`.

Do you think it's for the sake of simplicity or there's a logical reason ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`ObservableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff653818.aspx) is part of Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation - i.e. Prism. It's also been implemented in [MVVM Light](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight) and [MVVM Foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/).

[`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) is part of System.ComponentModel - i.e. it's in the core libraries.

So, if you are not already including Prism or one of the other frameworks I'd stick with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There seems to be little point in including it just to get this one class.

Comment: An ObserveableObject is also implemented, I believe, in MVVM Light.

Comment: Indeed. I was looking at some projects already made using MVVM Light (edit I confused the frameworks). So in my case I'll probably want to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go so far as to say if you are implementing a lot of ViewModels, there's a lot of plumbing code necessary to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and you'd be better off either creating your own ViewModel base class, or using one of the ones provided for you by an MVVM framework ([MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) being my framework of choice).

Otherwise, you're really not being very "DRY" (Don't repeat yourself).

*Edit - Accidently a thought*

Keep in mind that ObservableObject is usually just a lighter weight implementation of the same basic things a ViewModel class would, giving you INPC, but leaving out some of the other things you might use in a full ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, with all else being equal, I'd suggest going with an approach where you implement interfaces versus derive from ancestor classes.  You can implement as many interfaces as you please, but you only get one parent, so I prefer to use my parent "wisely".  In a case where I can get what I want implementing an interface, I prefer to leave my options open for inheritance later.

Comment: With something like ObservableObject, if you inherit from this, and later need to inherit from another class, you could ensure the new superclass inherits from ObservableObject.