# IsVisible not loading correctly in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I've got a ListView with some items inside, each item have some buttons but depends by his own data.

My xaml:

```
<ListView
        x:Name="ListViewRepartos"
        Margin="10"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        HasUnevenRows="True">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame Margin="10" BackgroundColor="{Binding ColorVisita}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />



                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Text="Cliente:" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Text="Direccion:" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Text="Importe:" />

                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                Text="{Binding Cliente}" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"
                                Text="{Binding Direccion}" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                Text="{Binding Importe}" />


                            <StackLayout
                                Grid.Row="5"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Command="{Binding Entregar}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding BotonesVisibles}"
                                        Text="Entregar" />
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Command="{Binding Llevame}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding BotonesVisibles}"
                                        Text="Llevame" />
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Command="{Binding Cobrar}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding BotonCobrosVisible}"
                                        Text="Cobros" />
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Command="{Binding Modificar}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding BotonModificarVisible}"
                                        Text="Modificar" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

.cs loading items for ListView:

```
 var resultado = new ObservableCollection<Modelos.Reparto>(Utils.Campos.Repartos.Select(q => ActivarBotones(q)).Where(q => q != null).ToList());
            Utils.UIHandler.RunOnUI(() => { 
                this.ListViewRepartos.ItemsSource = null;
                this.ListViewRepartos.ItemsSource = resultado;
                ListViewRepartos.EndRefresh();
            });
```

I load the item and activate the buttons with `ActivarBotones`:

```
private Modelos.Reparto ActivarBotones(Modelos.Reparto q)
    {
        try
        {                
            q.SetBotones(this);
            return q;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.UIHandler.ErrorDebug("ListaRepartos: Warning", ex.Message, Utils.UIHandler.MessageLevel.Warning);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Where `SetBotones` is in my model:

```
 public bool BotonesVisibles
    {
        get { return Visitado == EstadoVisita.NoVisitado; }
    }

    public bool BotonCobrosVisible
    {

        get {
            return Visitado == EstadoVisita.Entregado || Visitado == EstadoVisita.EntregadoMod;
        }
    }
    public bool BotonModificarVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return Visitado == EstadoVisita.EntregadoMod;
        }
    }

public void SetBotones(Controladores.Controlador Host)
    {
        this.Entregar = new Command(() => {
            Host.Unico(async () => {
                Utils.UIHandler.NavPush(new Vistas.Entregar(this.DatosCabecera, this.DatosCobro, this));
            });
        });
        this.Llevame  = new Command(() => {
            Host.Unico(async () => {
                Utils.UIHandler.RunOnUI(() => { 
                    ....
            });
        });
        this.Cobrar = new Command(() => {
            Host.Unico(async () => {
                Utils.UIHandler.NavPush(new Vistas.DatosPago(this.DatosCabecera));
            });
        });
        this.Info     = new Command(() => {
            Host.Unico(async () => {
                Utils.UIHandler.NavPush(new Vistas.DatosCliente(this.DatosCliente));
            });
        });
        this.Modificar = new Command(() => {
            Host.Unico(async () => {
                Utils.UIHandler.NavPush(new Vistas.AlbaranFactura(this.DatosCabecera,this.DatosCliente));
            });
        });
    }
```

But when i see the View in with real data, sometimes it display correctly, and sometimes not, also if go into item tapped and comes back by back button, it loads correctly fitted the buttons.

This image is an example image:

[image]

Any idea what i am doing wrong or why is not displaying correctly always the buttons ?

EDIT:

I've change the projecto to mvvm but still getting white spaces because don't display the correct buttons:

xaml:

```
<StackLayout
                                Grid.Row="5"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Command="{Binding Entregar}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding BotonesVisibles}"
                                        Text="Entregar" />
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Command="{Binding Llevame}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding BotonLlevarVisible}"
                                        Text="Llevame" />
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Command="{Binding Cobrar}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding BotonCobrosVisible}"
                                        Text="Cobros" />
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Command="{Binding Modificar}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding BotonModificarVisible}"
                                        Text="Modificar" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
```

> Model:

```
public EstadoVisita visitado = EstadoVisita.NoVisitado;

    public EstadoVisita Visitado
    {
        get
        {
            return visitado;
        }
        set
        {
            if(visitado == EstadoVisita.NoVisitado) { botonesvisibles = true; botonllevarvisible = true; }
            if(visitado == EstadoVisita.Entregado || visitado == EstadoVisita.EntregadoMod) { botoncobrosvisible = true; botonllevarvisible = false; botonesvisibles = false; }
            if(visitado == EstadoVisita.EntregadoMod) { botonmodificarvisible = true; botonllevarvisible = false; botonesvisibles = false; }
        }
    }

    public bool botonesvisibles = true;
    public bool BotonesVisibles
    {
        get { return botonesvisibles; }
        set { botonesvisibles = value; }
    }
    public bool botoncobrosvisible;
    public bool BotonCobrosVisible
    {
        get { return botoncobrosvisible; }
        set { botoncobrosvisible = value; }
    }
    public bool botonmodificarvisible;
    public bool BotonModificarVisible
    {
        get { return botonmodificarvisible; }
        set { botonmodificarvisible = value; }
    }
    public bool botonllevarvisible = true;
    public bool BotonLlevarVisible
    {
        get { return botonllevarvisible; }
        set { botonllevarvisible = value; }
    }
```

Any other thing to consider?

Comment: You need to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface for the Model that you are using. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667408/how-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-in-xamarin-forms. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093180/observableobject-or-inotifypropertychanged-on-viewmodels. These can help you.

Comment: @Nikhil but, i was looking to do in this way, is not possible? Why? I was looking for a answer because why not works perfectly but sometimes it does.

Comment: It would be taking the perviously set value. That is the reason why it doesn't work perfectly.

Comment: ViewModels generally implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, which means that the class fires a PropertyChanged event whenever one of its properties changes. The data binding mechanism in Xamarin.Forms attaches a handler to this PropertyChanged event so it can be notified when a property changes and keep the target updated with the new value.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT already change but still having issues. question edit with new code.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609258/how-to-hide-the-error-label-in-xamarin-forms-when-the-entry-field-is-not-visibl